# jQuery datepicker doesn't work on PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Here is my website- http://www.danfords.com/

I use jQuery datepicker on top right Arrival & Departure field.
With the same code in Tablet/Smartphone view datepicker works perfectly but in my pc that doesn't work.

Code-

```
                    <fieldset>
            <label for="arrival">Arrival</label>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="DateIn"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="departure">Departure</label>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="DateOut"/>
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two elements with the same id `datepicker` repeated for your tablet and PC html elements. If ids repeat, jQuery works only with the first match. Since your tablet element is placed first, it works on the tablet and not on PC.

Comment: You have to give unique ids for your html elements and initialize datepicker for each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your footer html to work on pc.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        'changeMonth': true,
        'changeYear': true,

    });
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
        'changeMonth': true, 
        'changeYear': true
    });
});
```